# AWS Step Functions - Choice

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Given this input (which is output from a previous map task):

```
[
  {
    "result": {
      "validated": true,
      "order": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "result": {
      "validated": true,
      "order": "2"
    }
  }
]
```

how do I access the validated flag in a choice task. I would have thought it is:

```
"Choice": {
  "Type": "Choice",
  "Choices": [
    {
      "Variable": "$.result[0].validated",
      "BooleanEquals": true,
      "Next": "Success"
    }
  ],
```

but that doesn't work - I get "Invalid path '$.result[0].validated': The choice state's condition path references an invalid value".

Also I will never know how many 'results' will be in that array (produced by the map task). How can I process the 'validated' flag to check that they are all true? Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi with the given input it is evident that '$.result[0].validated' will be invalid as '$' represents the root of the input and you are accessing 'result' on the root which does not exist. '$[0].result.validated' should work instead.